# Bluetooth not working - No default controller available

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, mouse

Just booted up my ubuntu desktop for the first time in a couple of months and suddenly my bluetooth mouse isn't working anymore.  Here's some things I have tried:

bluetoothctl:

```
[ ~ ] bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# devices
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
quitetooth]#
```

btmgmt:

```
[ ~ ] btmgmt power on
Set Powered for hci0 failed with status 0x14 (Permission Denied)
[ ~ ] sudo btmgmt power on
Set Powered for hci0 failed with status 0x11 (Invalid Index)
```

systemctl:

```
[ ~ ] systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-05-02 16:50:19 EDT; 6min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 9774 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38299)
     Memory: 660.0K
        CPU: 45ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─9774 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 02 16:50:19 Sonny systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 02 16:50:19 Sonny bluetoothd[9774]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
May 02 16:50:19 Sonny systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 02 16:50:19 Sonny bluetoothd[9774]: Starting SDP server
May 02 16:50:19 Sonny bluetoothd[9774]: Bluetooth management interface 1.22 initialized
```

hciconfig:

```
[ ~ ] hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 34:CF:F6:24:51:84  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
        UP RUNNING 
        RX bytes:20537 acl:0 sco:0 events:3294 errors:0
        TX bytes:813340 acl:0 sco:0 commands:3293 errors:0
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0x0f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF 
        Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
        Name: ''
        Class: 0x000000
        Service Classes: Unspecified
        Device Class: Miscellaneous, 
        HCI Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Revision: 0x237e
        LMP Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Subversion: 0x237e
        Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)
```

dmesg:

```
[ ~ ] sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.134998] Spectre V2 : Enabling Speculation Barrier for firmware calls
[    0.344755] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.366640] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] only partially covers this bridge
[    2.595340] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.16 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 4
[    2.595346] amdgpu 0000:0c:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    4.041808] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.058801] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.058821] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.058822] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.058825] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.058827] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.058829] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.361694] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.361698] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.361701] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.092357] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[    6.096357] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version command failed (-110)
[  813.325416] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.3 build 0 week 24 2017
[  813.327479] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 1
[  813.327483] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[  813.327484] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[  813.327486] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[  813.327487] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[  813.327488] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[  813.343266] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
[  813.343298] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x24800
[  813.343301] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 126-5.22
[  814.722835] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[  814.723277] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1347672 usecs
[  814.723333] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[  814.738280] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 14613 usecs
[  814.738285] Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
[  814.752911] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc
[  814.758284] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[  814.761286] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.3 build 126 week 5 2022
```

I also tried opening the "Bluetooth Manager" gui app from the System menu but it seems to just instantly close immediately after opening.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Additional system info:

```
[ ~ ] uname -a
Linux Sonny 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
[ ~ ] lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

Comment: For completeness, have you checked the mouse battery?

Comment: yep, mouse has lights that show when its on

Comment: Please edit to include results for `sudo dmesg|egrep-i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Updated! Thanks!  @Jeremy31

Comment: Did you close the lid at about 800 seconds after booting?  You might need a 6.2 version kernel to fix

Comment: @Jeremy31 - its a desktop not a laptop so there's no lid.  I already updated my kernel version to the max that the automatic software updater had available - I guess I'll need to do something more manual to get to 6.2?  What do you think is different in version 6.2 that will help?

Its weird because it worked fine for the last 2 years and only recently broke, seemingly for no reason...

Comment: Some of those cards for desktops needed a wire from the chip to the motherboard

Comment: But this worked for ~2 years before breaking in the last month!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as mentioned above. The fix that worked for me was to first remove the corresponding kernel modules and then re-adding them.

Check active bluetooth kernel modules

```
lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth            1036288  54 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
```

For me the controller was found after removing **btusb** and **btintel** and then re-adding them.

```
modprobe -r btusb
modprobe -r btintel
modprobe usb
modprobe btintel
```

Verify that the bluetooth controller is found

```
$ bluetoothctl                                                       [21:06:45]
Agent registered
[CHG] Controller 08:9D:F4:4C:B2:2D Pairable: yes
```